# email the downloadable file

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

I have a function which converts a data a gridview into excel file. When I run this function the file is automatically downloaded.But I want to directly email this file when it is completely converted into excel. How can I?

```
public static void ExportToExcel(System.Web.HttpResponse Response, Control grd, string PageHeading, string reportFileName)
        {
            Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(1));
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
            Response.BinaryWrite(Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());
            Response.Charset = "";
            //this.EnableViewState = false;
            Response.Write("<html xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\">");
            Response.Write("<br />");

            /*
            StringWriter twHead = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter hwHead = new HtmlTextWriter(twHead);
            lblPageHeading.RenderControl(hwHead);

            Response.Write(twHead.ToString());
            */
            Response.Write("<div style='font-family: Arial;font-size: 18px;color: #175494;padding-left: 2px;text-align: left;margin-left: 15px;'>" + PageHeading + "</div>");
            Response.Write("<br />");

           if(grd!=null) {
                try
                {

                    foreach (TableCell tableCell in ((GridView)grd).HeaderRow.Cells)
                    {
                        tableCell.Attributes.Clear();
                        tableCell.Attributes["style"] = "padding-left: 5px;padding-right: 5px;padding-top: 5px;font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold;font-family: Arial;color: #ffffff;text-decoration: none !Important;background:#0d293f;";

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the excel file off programmatically to a known location, then attach it in the email using the @file_attachments parameter in the sp_send_dbmail sproc.